# Suppress Dialog box using Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Using google script i am trying to create a custom Gmail add-on. In the widget i have configure a external link, when i click the widget it opens the link in a pop-up dialog box.

Is there any possibility to have the application opened inside the card instead of dialog box.

As shown in below screenshot, when we click "Get Started" button, the link gets opened as a dialog box.

[Current App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIj6M.png)
[Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeOE2.png)

We are expecting everything within the card instead of dialog box as shown in below message,

[Link opened inside card instead of dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHhqw.png)

I have attached the script and manifest i tried.

Script:

```
    function loadContent(event) {

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  //card1.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Feedback'));
  //var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('openLinkCallback');
  var action = CardService.newAuthorizationAction().setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.google.com/');
  //var authButton = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Begin Authorization').setAuthorizationAction(CardService.newAuthorizationAction().setAuthorizationUrl('https://bridgeqa.paypalcorp.com/aspire'));

  card.addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()

    .addWidget(
      CardService.newImage()
      .setImageUrl("https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vQscom5E3ZyC_8uTqOgs8d4-Pny7whZNZ6KTU1r57cjF85iHNfwp7d6nlwlw3AqVQU2cqWJJwjnS12W/pub?w=289&amp;h=318")
      .setAltText("Aspire")
      )

    .addWidget(CardService.newImage()
               .setImageUrl("https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vTFW56ya0BSy3vLQSb3TqwjMaz2oe5jVgI0PJ2HAPGEQBMQ8oVsvyOYyHDInD5c8fG1FsVwfS7ZGE81/pub?w=295&amp;h=100")
               .setAltText("Aspire")
               .setAuthorizationAction(action)
    )



   /*.addWidget(
      CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Login')
      .setAuthorizationAction(action)
      .setBackgroundColor('#009cde')
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    )*/

    );
    return [card.build()];
}
```

Manifest:

```
    {
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Aspire – Testing Changes",
    "logoUrl": "https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vQscom5E3ZyC_8uTqOgs8d4-Pny7whZNZ6KTU1r57cjF85iHNfwp7d6nlwlw3AqVQU2cqWJJwjnS12W/pub?w=289&amp;h=318",
    "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "loadContent",
        "enabled": true
      },
    "primaryColor": "#00cf92",
    "secondaryColor": "#009cde",
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://www.google.com/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Could someone please let me know whether its feasible?

Comment: The [documentation ](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/widgets) provides you information about what is and what is not possible within a widget. You can try to mimic the content of a website within the widget by pasting the correspondent text and images, but you cannot just openthe whole website as it is inside the widget.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the documentation, it was helpful.